# Subscribe to particular object changes in svelte store

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

I have a svelte store state object named articles which looks like this:

```js
{
  docs: [],
  pagination: {
    page: -1,
    pageSize: 10,
    next: -1,
    prev: -1,
    first: -1,
    last: -1
  },
  currentDocIndex: -1
}
```

Currently the subscribed handler fires on any change in the object. But I'd like to be able to fire particular changes e.g. when currentDocIndex has obtained a new value.

Would I have to split up my store state object into derived stores in order to achieve this or is there a simpler way?

Comment: The subscribed handler will always fire on any change in the state object. You can filter out the state change using a state prop(s) cache in the subscribed handler and ignore otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to create a custom store, check out the example on this link

[Svelte custom store example](https://svelte.dev/repl/6bbba7d0d97e498fb587b416adbed2d9?version=3.35.0)

the docs section will get updated only when you click on the increment button

Comment: Did you know you can directly get and set store props. Example get: $state.pagination.pageSize and set: $state.currentDocIndex += 1

Comment: Yeah, but using a custom store will let you control when you want to notify subscribers about the changes, unfortunately, this works when you are referencing the store from the context

Comment: Yes, it's not really reactive.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked / cloned the derived store to create a "derive" store, which returns the derived result and a bit map of fired stores.

See this repl: [Derived store  returns bit map of fired stores](https://svelte.dev/repl/65d2b1ce0a8945feac309db1c5f3f2f9?version=3.35.0)